Efficiently multiply a special sparse 3D tensor with a vector in python
I have a 3D tensor T of size (nrows, ncols, ncols), which I would like to multiply with a vector x of size nrows.
However, T will be a huge sparse tensor with 6×6 nonzero entries in each row;
thus, it would be useful to store T in a sparse format.
The most convenient way would be to define a Tsparse tensor of size (nrows, 6, 6) and a "pointer" matrix p of size (nrows, 6) which stores the indices of the nonzero entries for each row.
In this case, how can Tsparse and x be multiplied in a Python code? If there were a direct way using NumPy or SciPy, I would highly prefer that option.
Anyway, here is my MWE, which needs to be rewritten based on what was stated above:
import numpy as np

nrows = 100
ncols = 20
p = np.zeros((nrows, 6), dtype=int)

for i in range(nrows):
    p[i, :] = np.random.choice(np.arange(ncols), 6, replace=False)

T = np.zeros((nrows, ncols, ncols))
Tsparse = np.zeros((nrows, 6, 6))
for i in range(nrows):
    for j in range(6):
        for k in range(6):
            entry = np.random.rand()
            T[i, p[i, j], p[i, k]] = entry
            Tsparse[i, j, k] = entry
            
x = np.array(np.random.rand(nrows))

res = np.tensordot(T, x, axes=([0], [0]))

#The goal would be to form Tsparse * x instead of T * x

print(res)


How big is ncols in reality?  If you could flatten the last two dimensions into one you could use scipy.sparse formats.

@DanielF ncols is around 3000-5000. In general, nrows >> ncols [even nrows = (ncols - 1) * ncols / 2].

Are you implementing an FEM analysis routine?   That has far more manipulation tricks available in established literature than I'd want to write out in an answer, but considering 6x6 matrices (which is standard for Cauchy stress-strain tensors) and summing up over a triangular selection of what look like nodes, it makes me feel like you may be trying to reinvent the wheel.

@DanielF In the T tensor, the first dimension corresponds to Eucledian distances between (selected) pairs of 3D Cartesian points, while the last two dimensions denote pairs of Cartesian coordinates. The T[i, j, k] entry represents the second derivative of the ith distance with respect to the jth and kth Cartesian coordinates. Since the ith distance depends only on 6 coordinates, there will be a 6×6 nonzero matrix for each i. If there are existing modules which can treat/generate this tensor, then I would be happy to use it.

@DanielF Note that this T tensor should be multiplied with the gradient of a function f, dependent on selected distances, to obtain fs Hessian in Cartesians. Of course, the first-order derivatives of the distances are also required to produce this Hessian, but they form a sparse matrix D of size (nrows, 6), which can be efficiently treated with scipy.sparse.

@DanielF So the goal is in fact to use the T tensor in a chain rule. See also the last formula of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090199/tensor-calculus-second-order-derivatives (in our case, the mu-s are the Cartesians and the x-s are the distances).
